# Updating JTabbedPane components

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I am writing a simple chat program that shows different dialogs in different tabs of a `JTabbedPane`. I used a `JTextArea` to display the dialog. I added a `JTextArea` to the tab like this:

```
 JTextArea referenceToAppend = new JTextArea();
 JTabbedPane.addTab(title,new JPanel(new JScrollBar(referenceToAppend)));
```

I put the reference `referenceToAppend` into a `List`, then when I need to append text I do
the following :

```
 List.get(index).append(textForAppend);
```

The problem is: my application becomes unresponsive. How can I solve this problem? I looked up a lot of information on forums and of course, Oracle. I can't find what I need. Maybe I was inattentive or may be I am not understanding something simple. I will be very grateful if someone could give a simple example or link to another forum where they discuss this problem.

Comment: It sounds like you're blocking the [*Event Dispatch Thread*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Posting more of your code, or an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), will help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). It allows you to perform operations in a background thread an report information to the Event Dispatch Thread. If you need to block on a socket read, you need to do that on a background thread to keep the UI responsive.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeffrey and Devon_C_Miller ! I was known about single thread model in swing but thought that operation of appending text will not take much time.But as I understand the problem is much deeper - I must work with swing components only in EDT.The next code  solve all my problems:   new SwingWorker(){  public Object doInBackGround(){return null}  public void done(){JTextArea.append(text)} }.execute(); Thanks A Lot !!